# Enable "Filename was downloaded from the internet..." prompt in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, security, alert, core-services, launch-services

I have an app that downloads ZIP files from my server, and can download plugins from other servers. Before being able to open these files, I would like to present one of the classic '"Filename.html" is a (file type) downloaded from the internet. Are you sure you want to open it?" messages when first attempting to open the file, much like Google Chrome does when you save a HTML file and attempt to open it:
[image]

I've read that this is enabled by setting a special file attribute, but I'm not entirely sure what attribute it is, and how to set it on these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File Quarantine is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Carbon/RN-LaunchServices/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed what I was looking for. Strangely, I just could not find this on the internet. Weird.

Comment: The original unlabeled link is broken.  It was pointing at "Launch Services" (which is currently at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference).  Right now, however, I can't find an answer to the OP's question there since much of the API is deprecated and, in typical Apple fashion, there's no information on what should be used instead.